# Why is my Backend Application is not running in Springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, compiler-errors

```java
    package com.caffiend.backend;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class BackendApplication {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(BackendApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

I am unable to run the backend because I keep getting errors in this file. I have the latest version of JDK 11 and the same code is running smoothly on my colleagues computer but I do not understand why I am getting this error specifically.
[photo of error on VS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PA456.png)

Comment: You should post the error messages not with a link to an image somewhere but write them down here. Looks like you have not included the libraries into your project - did you start your project with Spring Initializr (https://start.spring.io) ? Which build manager tool do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Open `VSCode` and go to extension and search for "spring". You will find `Spring Boot Extension Pack`. You should install it, and restart `VSCode` then it will work.

Comment: I tried doing that but I am having the exact same problem. I have downloaded all the required extensions and plugins.